# Change size of only one item in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-inflate, android-layoutparams

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.button.setText("button" + +position);    
    if(position == 0){
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams);
        viewHolder.button.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 200;
        params.width = 200;
        viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }else{
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams);
        viewHolder.button.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.width = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Using this code in the adapter of `GridView` I'm trying to give a custom size to the first item of `GridView`, but it changes size of all items in the row but items of other columns stay normal. 
So how can I make only 1 item to be changed in `GridView`?

Comment: you need an `else` part to your if. remember, the same view is recycled for several items

Comment: I do also have an `else` part in my `if` I shortened the code to make it clear. The same problem exists also with `else`

Comment: and in your else block, do you set the height and width?

Comment: Yes I set to the original height and width which is RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: please edit your  question to add that information

Comment: Better to use different viewHolder for that particular row

Comment: I edited the code, and also it does not change the size of items in other columns only the ones in the same row

Answer (score 0):

```
if(position == 0){
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams);
    viewHolder.button.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 200;
    params.width = 200;
    viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
}else{
   //make other item normal
}
```